# Azure Event Hubs for Vital application loads

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, high-availability, disaster-recovery

Is anyone using Azure Event Hubs for Vital application load where the RPO and RTO requirements are 0 and having more 30+ consuming applications? Since Azure Event Hubs doesn't have inbuilt replication across the clusters, I'm interested to see how such vital application(if any)

- are handling HA and DR requirements?
- handling 0 data loss requirement
- if separate Event Hubs clusters are created in two different, how to handle clients during a DR since there is no offset mapping and consumer offset replication across clusters

Comment: You might want Service Bus instead of Event Hubs.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services

Comment: Agreed, some reason we were asked to used Event Hubs, so trying to solve these with Event Hubs and wondering if any org already have some patterns